# Whitespacing in html, anyway to display it as such

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, formatting, whitespace

I have a good amount of content that stores their data in a database with plenty of whitespace, which shows how they want it to display on page. Stackoverflow can change it up with the code tag. (the second way is how it looks in the database, and how they want it to display, the first way is how it currently is display)  Is there anything I can do with the existing html?

step 1
step 2
step 3
step 4

```
step 1
step 2
step 3
step 4
```

**Edit:** Hoping not to use the pre tag. Maybe taking my Model (lets say Model.MyHtml) and applying something to check for whitespace, but I am not sure how...

Comment: have you tried using <pre>?

Comment: "Stackoverflow can change it up with the <code> tag", yep, that's it

Comment: I was hoping for something other than the pre tag to keep the style. But I am guessing this isn't possible without doing a find and replace on my model that houses the html?

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
     step 1
step 2
  step 3
step 4
</pre>
```

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/tvxU9/

Comment: didn't really want to use pre tag, as I want to keep the style

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to preserver the whitespace and keep the style. good ol' css (i had forgotten about this)

white-space: pre-wrap;

or pre-line works if you don't want tabs